# How to resolve: "Could not load type 'System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer' from assembly 'WindowsBase, Version=4.0.0.0"?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading, mstest

I'm unit testing a WPF project whose target Framework is.NET Framework 4.7.2.

I created a MSTest test project whose target Framework is .NET 7.0.

Here is a class in the WPF project I try to unit test. It has a DispatcherTimer variable.
And I think the it is referenced the Assembly WindowsBase (C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.7.2\WindowsBase.dll)

```
using System.Windows.Threading;

public class Battery : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
       ......

    private DispatcherTimer dtBatteryTimeout;
     
    public Battery()
    {
         
    }
    ...
}
```

Here is my unit test method. The method can be compiled successfully but when I debug test,
it will throw the exception "Could not load type 'System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer' from assembly 'WindowsBase, Version=4.0.0.0".

```
        [TestMethod()]
        public void BatteryTest()
        {
            Battery _battery = new Battery();  //throw exception here.
            Assert.AreEqual(_battery.batteryLevel, "0");
        }
```

So, How to resolve this exception, How can I set the MSTestProject to reference the same windowsbase.dll as the WPF project? Any workaround?

windowsbase.dll in wpf project targeting .NET 4.7.2.
[image]

windowsbase.dll in MSTest project targeting .NET 7.0.
[image]

MSTest project dependencies

I don't know why the windowsbase.dll from Microsoft.NETCore.App does not work and don't know how to add a correct reference.

[image]

Comment: Why is your test project targeting .NET 7.0?

Comment: as @JimFoye asks , why to mix versions? you should use the same project version for both

Comment: .NET 7 is a .NET Core family, and it's not compatible with .NET Framework family. You have to use the same technology stack.

Comment: When I create the MSTest project in VS 2022, the "Framework" ComboBox only has two options to choose, .Net 6.0 and Net. 7.0.